# Selected text angular2 with *ngFor

Tags: select, angular, ngfor

I have done some research but I can't find the solution.
I have done a schema of what I want, to be more clear if my explanations are not clear.

I have a select model like this :

```
<select required [(ngModel)]="value" (ngModelChange)="valueChanged($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let v of values" [ngValue]="v">
    {{v.short_desc}}
  </option>
</select>
```

My values are for example :

1. Option 1
2. Some awesome text with text
3. Option 2

The width of the select is small, so I need to truncate the selected option if the text is too long.

But I don't know how to do this, if I change "{{v.short_desc}}", all options are impacted (obviously), not only the one selected.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks for your help.

[image: schema]

Comment: Add style="text-overflow: ellipsis;" which may can even help

Comment: Hey ! 
Thanks for the answer but it seems that ellipsis doesn't work with select option unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Use a `width` value for your `select`

also, remember to put your full length text description into a `title` property

```
<option value="1" title="This is my lengthy explanation of what this selection really means, so since you only see 1 on the drop down list you really know that you're opting to elect me as King of Willywarts!  Always be sure to read the fine print!">1</option>
```

Comment: Hey !

Thanks for your answer.
I guess you suggest to put a greater width value for my select, but I can't.
Futhermore, I can't put the long text into a title property because it has to be readable. Otherwise I would have done.